# POWER BI : Calculate the percentage excluding last 5 days

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to compute the percentage of Free to Paid Sales conversions for a particular period.

[image]

Sales become paid after the threshold of  5 days. So Conversion % should exclude the last 5 days. Expected output is below.

[image]

Below are the measure I have created.

1. FreeSales      : `SUM( DATA[Free_Trials])`
2. Conversions : `SUM(DATA[Conversions])`
3. Conv  %       : `Calculate ( DIVIDE( FreeSales/Conversions,0), DATESBETWEEN(DATA[DATE], STARTDATE, ENDDATE-5))`

(P.S:  `STARTDATE` & `ENDDATE` are the min & max values from the date slicer)

Conv % is not working properly . It giving same value for all the rows in the table.  Please help to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you will have couple of slicers in the report?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a calculated column with the below DAX formula.

```
Column2 =
VAR C = MAX ( Sheet1[Date] )
VAR RESULT =
     IF (
         ( Sheet1[Date] ) = C,
         0,
           IF (
              Sheet1[Date] = C - 1,
              0,
                IF (
                  Sheet1[Date] = C - 2,
                  0,
                    IF (
                      Sheet1[Date] = C - 3,
                      0,
                        IF (
                          Sheet1[Date] = C - 4,
                          0,
                  CALCULATE ( DIVIDE ( SUM ( Sheet1[Paid Sales] ), SUM ( Sheet1[Free Sales] ) ) )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
RETURN
    RESULT
```

[image: Output]

If this post helps, then please consider Accept it as the solution to help the other members find it more quickly.

Comment: If it works then just let me know and accept it as the answer, and if it doesn't then also let me know. Thanks.